# Regex Help Required to ignore colon and accepting dot in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to know the regex which can ignore the colon (:) but accept the (.) in a string so basically I need to find all the strings which start with . and ends with a paranthesis, but not start with a colon (:) and ends with paranthesis

String : 
span.menu-item-parent:contains('Providers')).parent().next('ul').find('span.menu-item-parent')

Regex I am using is    .\w*(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`\w` is shorthand for "word" characters, which mean letters and numbers. If you want to accept additional characters you need to use a character class. For example, `[\w:]+` means "at least one word character or semicolon". To modify your current expression, try `.[\w:]*\(`

Sidenote, be careful with the `.` there. `.` means "any character". If you want it to match a literal fullstop/period, you need to escape it with a backslash same as you've done with the open parenthesis.

To achieve the later-stated goal of "finding text between a dot and an open-parenthesis", then you want to be looking at lookaheads and lookbehinds or captures. Here's how you'd do it with lookaheads and behinds:

```
(?<=\.).+(?=\()
```

Or with captures:

```
\.(.+)\(
```

Comment: I am using this regex 
.\w*\(

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying you should replace the `\w` with perhaps `[\w:]` to indicate that you want to match word characters *or* a semicolon.

Comment: I basically want to find the word which starts with dot (.) and end with first paranthesis , but I am also getting the string starting with colon (:) and ends with paranthesis..

your suggestion doesn't help here

Comment: That's not what your stated objective was in your original question, which is the question I was addressing.

Comment: can you help with this though?

Comment: You need to update your question to state exactly what you're trying to achieve. That way when other users find this thread they will see cohesion between the question and the answer.